# Force TP Link router DNS traffic through port 53

Tags: networking, router, dns

I have recently purchased a TP-Link Archer C5 wireless router and am administering the home WiFi network. There are quite a few kids who use this network and my aim is to block pornographic content through this network. OpenDNS seemed to be the best option to setup on the router.

If any devices using this WiFi have their own hard-coded DNS settings, it circumvents the router's DNS settings. The solution I found after visiting many forums is to force all the DNS traffic through port 53 of the router. This forces all the network traffic to use the router's DNS settings.

I couldn't find any solution on how to implement this in a TP-Link router. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are asking a consumer grade router to perform enterprise grade functionality, which it isn't capable of out of the box. DD-WRT or OpenWRT may be capable of this, but I can't say for certain. It sounds to me like you have the incorrect hardware or software for the job at hand.

Comment: so there is no way to do this with this hardware and default software?

Comment: I don't think so... I looked through the user guide of that model and it doesn't have DNS Filtering (DNS Filtering on an Asus RT-N66U http://imgur.com/ef5ULYx) built in like some other routers, and although there is some stuff in Advanced→Access Control, you may be able to make a custom access or target rule, I think messing with 53/UDP could have other side effects when it isn't designed for it. Using DD-WRT or OpenWRT will work (I double checked, it's called DNS Intercept, and is enabled at the SSH command shell, not the GUI)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your router specifically, but the general idea is to create a firewall rule (aka access rule) that blocks all outgoing UDP (and optionally TCP) traffic on port 53 except to the addresses of your OpenDNS servers.

Keep in mind that even if you successfully create this rule, a dedicated and clever user can still use a proxy, VPN or other methods to get at sites that OpenDNS blocks.